# show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln(x)dx=-\gamma=\Gamma'(1) $

Tags: integration

show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln(x)dx= -\gamma=\Gamma'(1)$$

where $\gamma$ is [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant)

I started with $$\Gamma(z)=\left[ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z/k}\right]^{-1}.$$

by take log then derivative with respect to z and put z=1 I got $\Gamma'(1)=-1-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$

but I dont know how to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$ I know the answer is 1 but how ?

this is my way . can any one show different way ? or give me how to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$

Comment: Is saying $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log x\,dx = \Gamma'(1)$ legitimate?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes

Comment: Well, then you're done, since $\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$.

Comment: Hehe...@DanielFischer , that almost looked as a trap.+1

Comment: @DanielFischer hehe but why $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/138455/4583) is related, but doesn't answer all of the questions here.

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh For example, you get $\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$ from the product representation $\Gamma(z) = e^{-\gamma z} \frac{1}{z}\prod\limits_{\nu = 1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{z}{\nu}\right)^{-1}e^{z/\nu}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is what i did but I dont know how to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$ I know the answer is 1 but how ?

Comment: @O.L. : thanks it is really has the answer but i make an edit which  show where is the sum I dont know how to compute

Comment: Telescopic sum is what you're looking for.

Comment: @karakfa: no I say different method to show $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ or the way to compute the sum which lead to show that $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$

Comment: To compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$ Start by the following $\lim_{k\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{k}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) =$

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{k}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}) = 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai thanks

Comment: that was telescopic sum.