# Prove that $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, gamma-function

Use the product formula for $1/\Gamma(z)$ to prove that $$\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$$

---

I know that for Euler constant $\gamma$,

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} =ze^{\gamma z}\prod _{k=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{z}{k})e^{-z/k}$$

But I cannot prove it properly. Please show me explicitly. Thank you:)

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461070

Comment: Take the reciprocals of both sides of your identity, and then take the logarithmic derivative of both sides. Since $\Gamma(1)=1$, this gives you $\Gamma'(1)/\Gamma(1) = \Gamma'(1) = \dots$.

Comment: I didnt see the question.thank you @hmedan.mnsh

Comment: Look up digamma function on wikipedia

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\log\Gamma(z)=-\log z-\gamma z-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\log\left(1+\frac zk\right)-\frac zk\right]\implies$$

$$\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-\frac1z-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k\frac k{k+z}-\frac1k\right)=-\frac1z-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+z}-\frac1k\right)\implies$$

$$\Gamma'(1)=\frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)}=-1-\gamma-\left(\frac12-1+\frac13-\frac12+\ldots\right)=-1-\gamma-(-1)=-\gamma$$