# Derivative of $\Gamma$ at $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

I've been given two definitions of the Gamma function, the integral defintion:

$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ (for $Re(z)>0$)

and the product definition (for $1/\Gamma$):

$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = ze^{\gamma z}\Pi_{n=1}^\infty ((1+\frac{z}{n})e^{-\frac{z}{n}})$

where $\gamma$ is [Euler's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

My lecturer has asserted that therefore (presumably from the product definition):

$\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$

but I can't see why this is true. Is this something that follows easily from these definitions? If it is I would appreciate some help or a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computing $ \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{\exp x} \ dx $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419026/computing-int-0-infty-frac-log-x-exp-x-dx)

Comment: I posted an answer using the product definition, but then I realized it has been posted before. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620328/prove-that-gamma1-gamma?rq=1

Comment: @RandomVariable thanks for pointing out that this is (exactly) the same as another question. I'm fairly new here - what's the convention now? Should I delete this question?

Comment: Search digamma function on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the product form and take the log of both sides, and then differentiate:
(Sorry, I have to write out the equations in LaTeX format, I don't know MathML well enough)

Take the log:
\begin{equation}
  - \log (\Gamma(z)) = \log(z) + \gamma z
  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \log \left( 1 + \frac{z}{n} \right) - \frac{z}{n} \right]
\end{equation}

Take the derivative of both sides with respect to z:
\begin{equation}
- \frac{\Gamma^{\prime}(z)}{\Gamma(z)} = \frac{1}{z} + \gamma 
 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1/n}{1+z/n} - \frac{1}{n} \right]
\end{equation}

Now insert z = 1 because we only care about the derivative at z = 1, and simplify the fraction with 1+1/n in the denominator (using $\Gamma(1) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}dt = 1$):
\begin{align}
- \Gamma' (1) = 1 + \gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n} \right] = 1 + \gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{n(n+1)} = \gamma. 
\end{align}
which is $\Gamma'(1) = - \gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Here if we use the integral definition we get:

$\Gamma'(z)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(t^{z-1})e^{-t}dt=\int_0^\infty \ln(t)t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$

thus $\Gamma'(1)=\int_0^\infty \ln(t)e^{-t}dt=-\gamma$