# Looking for Guidance: Behavior of $x!^{\frac{1}{x}}$...

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, gamma-function

On my own time, I've been trying to learn as much as I can about the upper levels of mathematics.  I recently came across the Gamma function: 
$$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)! = \int_{0}^{\infty}(t^{x-1}e^{-x})dt = \int_{0}^{1}(-\ln(t))^{x-1}dt$$
Therefore, obviously $x! = \int_{0}^{1}(-\ln(t))^{x-1}dt$ (this can also be verified by graphing both functions).  This reminded me of something I thought about a long time ago: $f(x)=(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}$.  Now that I understand more about mathematics, I (like many others both in general and on stackoverflow) was able to prove that $(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ diverges to $\infty$.  However, when calculating $\lim_{x\to0}(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}$, my intial guess that $\lim_{x\to0}(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\gamma=0.57721...$ was proven wrong.  I found that $\lim_{x\to0}(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}\approx0.5615...$.  This leads me to my first question.  Does this number have any significance?  Might it have any importance other than being the arbitrary number that's the answer to this question?  **[ANSWERED BY R_Berger]**

Moving on to my second question.  When I graphed this to verify my solution, I was surprised to see that the graph was practically a straight line (I expected more than a negligible curve of some type). Taking the derivative of this function would obviously be shown as $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^1\left(-\ln\left(t\right)\right)^{x}dt\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}.$$  I was unable to find the above derivative either by hand or by using a calculator.  So, is there a way to take the above derivative or any other variant of $x!$ (or $\Gamma(x-1)$)?  **[NO POINTERS GIVEN YET]**

Lastly, most importantly, and my primary reason for asking this question... My ultimate goal is finding $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^1\left(-\ln\left(t\right)\right)^{x}dt\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}.$  If you have any pointers or small **hints** on anything I could look into, that would very much be appreciated.  **[NO POINTERS GIVEN YET]**

If you take the time to read and answer this, I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For the first question: [$\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799420/derivative-of-gamma-at-1), not sure if it helps much.

Comment: Simply doing a derivation yields:$$ [\Gamma(x+1)^{-x}]'= -\Gamma(x+1)^{-x}(\ln \Gamma(x+1) + x\frac{\Gamma'(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)}) $$ and for $x=0$ everything is well defined and evaluates to $$  -\Gamma(1)^{0}(\ln \Gamma(1) + 0\frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)}) = -1(\ln 1 + 0\frac{\gamma}{1})=0.$$

Comment: CAS (MMA) evaluates $\lim_{x\to0}\Gamma(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}=1.$

Comment: The number you find is $\lim_{x\to 0} (x!)^{1/x} = e^{-\gamma} = 0.56145\cdots$. You can use [Stirlings approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to show that it convergest to a straight line of slope $1/e$ as $x\to\infty$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x!)^{1/x}}{x} = \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @R_Berger, Thanks for your input.  I did find myself that $\gamma(1)=−\gamma$, so its good have someone else affirm this fact.  From what I can tell, the derivation in your second comment of $[\Gamma(x+1)^{-x}]'$ is correct, however, the function I was looking to differentiate was $[\Gamma(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}]'$.  Sorry :(.  Also, I don't understand how $\lim_{x\to0}\Gamma(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}=1$ could possibly be correct, I believe this can be seen by just graphing the function.

Comment: @Winther, in my research I became aware of Stirling's approximation, but never took the time to further research it.  Out of my own personal curiosity, I have to verify the solution myself, and I will absolutely be taking the time now to learn about Stirling's approximation.  Prior to this, I did know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x!^{\frac{1}{x}}}=e$, so by just that alone, I would think it would stand to reason that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x!^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}=\frac{1}{e}$.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I should say that Stirlings is a bit of overkill to show this limit as it can be done without it. So if you managed to show it without it that's a better way

Comment: @Winther Stirling's Approximation is certainly good information for me to know.  I am, however, a little confused about how to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{-\gamma}$.

Comment: @supersmarty1234: Yes you are right.

Comment: I have confused $x^{-1}$ with $-x$ initially and then just copied your formula. Mathematica confirms @Winther's limit of $e^{-\gamma}$. Moreover it gives any finite series development of $\Gamma(x+1)^{x^{-1}}$ at $x=0$ (with linear term $\frac{\pi^2}{12}e^{-\gamma}$).

Comment: When you want to use derivations of the Gamma function, at some stage you have to work with Polygamma functions, then you can get some expressions for the derivatives. I think thats not simpler than Sterling for this problem. With the Sterling approximation the $x\to\infty$ should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

For limits of $f(x)^{1/x}$ sometimes one looks at logarithms, so we could look at $$\ln \Gamma(x+1)^{1/x} = \frac{\ln\Gamma(x+1)}{x}.$$
For $x\to0$ this looks like a case for *de l'Hospital*, for the denominator we get $1$ and for the numerator we have:

$$ \ln \Gamma(x+1)' = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)'}{\Gamma(x+1)}$$ at $x=0$ this evaluates (as you know) to $$\frac{-\gamma}{1}=-\gamma.$$

By exponentiating we recieve our $$e^{-\gamma}=\lim_{x\to0}\exp(\ln\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x})=\lim_{x\to0}\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x}$$

---

***Edit***

The case of $x\to\infty$:
Using the [Sterling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in terms of the $\Gamma$ function
$$ \Gamma(n+1)\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\big(\frac{n}{e}\big)^n$$ the expression of interest giving the slope is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)^\frac{1}{n}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \big(\sqrt{2\pi n}\big(\frac{n}{e}\frac{1}{n}\big)^n\big)^\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \big(2\pi n\big)^{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2}} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\big(\frac{n^n}{e^n}\big)^\frac{1}{n}}{n}=$$ 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (2\pi)^\frac{1}{n} \lim_{n\to\infty}(n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{e}=e^{-1}.$$

Comment: I don't know how I possibly made it more clear that I wasn't looking for an answer.  I was looking for pointers...  I'm sorry, but I have to kindly request that you remove the edits or at least revise them so that they're pointers rather than (what I presume is, as I'm not going to read it) the solution.

Comment: Soooo..........

Comment: I suggest you simply look into the [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation) of the Stirling approximation. That's in all cases o good one to know.

Comment: Did you not at all read my first comment? @R_Berger