# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1-e^{-2t})}{a^2+t^2}\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I was trying to evaluate the following integral which I found on Quora.

$$I =\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{\ln^2(\sin x)}{\pi^2+\ln^2(\sin x)}\right)\frac{\ln \cos x}{\tan x}\, dx $$

I used the substitution $\sin x = e^{-t}$ to get

$$I = \int\limits_0^\infty \ln\left(\frac{t^2}{\pi^2+t^2}\right)\ln\sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}\, dt$$

As I noticed,

$$\ln \left(\frac{t^2}{\pi^2+t^2}\right) = -2 \int\limits_0^\pi \frac{a}{a^2+t^2}\, da$$
And thus
$$I = -\int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^\pi \frac{a\ln(1-e^{-2t})}{a^2+t^2}\, da\, dt$$
If interchanging of the order of integration is allowed, then we get
$$I = -\int\limits_0^\pi a\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1-e^{-2t})}{t^2+a^2}\, dt\, da $$
Question :

1. Is the interchange of integration is allowed?
2. If yes, how can I evaluate the integral?

I tried to use the fact that $\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-au}\cos(ut)\, du = \frac{a}{a^2+t^2}$, but that made things more complicated.
Please help.

Comment: You may check the [answers in this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/523027/9340). Combining the observations therein, you can compute the value of your integral.

Comment: @Lee I will try to find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Use Tonelli to justify the change.

Comment: Maybe I was too fast with the duplicate vote (I forgot it gets closed by a single vote). If this doesn't answer your original integral ($I$) as you wish, it can be reopened.

Comment: @Zacky actually, I was satisfied. Sangchul Lee provided the link for my integral. I found one part of it there. I managed to solve for the second part.